# fopen and jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I'm pulling an employee staff list with datatables, around 2000+ records. Not all employees have a photo, so i want to use fopen to check to see if a photo exists. I've used this function with success elsewhere:

```
function getImage() {

    $pic = "https://my.website.edu/photos/" . $primaryKey . ".jpg";
    if(@fopen($pic, "r")) {
        return '<img src="' . $pic . '" width="140px" class="thumbnail" />';
    } else {
        return '<img src="https://my.website.edu/images/photo_not_available.png" width="140px" />';
    }
}
```

I'd like to reference it in jQuery Datatables server_proceesing.php file here:

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'user_id', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'user_id', 'dt' => 1 ),      
array( 'db' => 'fullname', 'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'title',  'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'department',   'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'campus',   'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'location',   'dt' => 6 )        
);
```

in the first array( 'db' => 'user_id', 'dt' => 0 ),

I know there is a formatter with pre-defined formats for numbers, dates etc. but i see no way to just echo the function. Is this even possible?

Comment: Doy you really need to return the function itself or is the result enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using everything inside the function without calling it.

```
array( 'db' => 'user_id', 
'dt' => 0, 
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {

$pic = "https://my.website.edu/photos/" . $primaryKey . ".jpg";
if(@fopen($pic, "r")) {
return '<img src="' . $pic . '" width="140px" class="thumbnail" />';
} else {
return '<img src="https://my.website.edu/images/photo_not_available.png" width="140px" />';
}
},
```

This works and generates my default no image available if needed. Now if i can just get my generated column of images to save to pdf, i'm gold. :) but that's another question. Thanks to all that responded.

Comment: If you want PDF output, take a look at [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). Good to hear it works!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `fopen` if all you want to do is `echo` the URL into an `<img>` tag. Try using [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to determine if the file exists, instead.

Comment: my understanding is file_exists only works if the file is on the same server.

Comment: @trf Oh you're checking for images outside of your server? That changes a lot. How comfortable are you with AJAX?